# Error Occured while designing Dialog in Qt

Tags: qt

The program name is GoToCell in the form I created a label and two push buttons and I wrote the code in main.cpp as follows:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include<QDialog>
#include "ui_GoToCell.h"
#include "GoToCell.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Ui::GoToCell ui;
    QDialog *dialog=new QDialog;
    ui.setupUi(dialog);
    dialog->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

While running it I'm getting the following errors:
GoToCell is not a member of ui
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misspelled object name in `objectName` property in the `GoToCell.ui` form. 
Change it to `GoToCell`. It will then execute.

Comment: The Object Name property is GoToCell and it is not GoToCell.ui. I'm still getting the error.